# Dropbox can not authenticate using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dropbox

I am trying to authenticate in Dropbox using Xamarin.Forms, I use the following code.

```
                this.oauth2State = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                var authorizeUri = DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorizeUri(OAuthResponseType.Token, AppKeyDropboxtoken, new Uri(RedirectUri), this.oauth2State, false, false, null, loginAgain);
                webView = new CustomWebview
                {
                    Source = authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri
                };
                webView.Navigating += this.WebViewOnNavigating;
                //Grid Layout
                Grid lyStack = new Grid
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        webView,
                        lyTitle,
                    },
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
                };
                this.Content = lyStack;
```

But when I submit the App to production, I get the following error message:

> Hi there,
>
> Your production key request was declined for the following reason:
>
> Your apps currently process the OAuth app authorization flow inside a
>   web view, instead of the system browser. The OAuth app authorization
>   flow should be processed in the user's system browser. See here for
>   more information:
>   https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize
>   .
>
> If you believe your app shouldn't have been declined, or to resubmit
>   your request, please email us at api-program@dropbox.com.

Comment: You can not use a `WebView` as you, "the developer", can mishandle/steal/etc... the user's creds. You need to use an "external" browser such as SFSafariViewController on iOS or ChromeCustomTabs on Android and as such will only have access to the refresh token, might want to look at `Xamarin.Auth` as it bundles all that in its nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.Auth solved the problem, that is the way it worked:

```
        private string oauth2State;
        private const string RedirectUri = "https://www.myredirecturl.com/en/";
        private string AccessToken { get; set; }
        private const string AppKeyDropboxtoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private void openDropbox()
        {
            this.oauth2State = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            var authorizeUri = DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorizeUri(OAuthResponseType.Token, AppKeyDropboxtoken, new Uri(RedirectUri), this.oauth2State, false, false, null, false);
            //Authorize URI
            OAuth2Authenticator auth = new OAuth2Authenticator
            (
                clientId: AppKeyDropboxtoken,
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri(authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri),
                redirectUrl: new Uri(RedirectUri),
                isUsingNativeUI: false
            );

            auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    Debug.Write("IsAuthenticated . . . . . ");
                    // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                    this.AccessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    Debug.WriteLine("AccessToken: " + this.AccessToken);
                    //Do Something
                }
            };

            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(auth);
        }
```

And intialize on the plataforms the Presenter,

Android on your OnCreate method

```
global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinAndroid.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init(this, bundle);
```

iOs on your AppDelegate.cs

```
global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinIOS.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init();
```